# Activity wont start with "startActivity();"

Tags: java, android

Here's my code for DroidArmoryActivity

```
package com.maxgenero.droidarmory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class DroidArmoryActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()) {

    case R.id.ibM4A1:
        Intent intentM4A1 = new Intent("com.maxgenero.droidarmory.M4A1GUN");
        startActivity(intentM4A1);
        break;

        }
    }
}
```

It's not starting the java file (Activity) at all, no errors. Btw, the case is looking for an imageButton.
Here's my Manifest, at least the part you need:

```
<activity android:name=".M4a1"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape">
              <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.maxgenero.droidarmory.M4A1" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And the file name for the java file is M4a1.java. If you need more info let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont see where you define a listener on your Button or your View that will be  clicked to launch the second Activity ??

```
yourView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

the second thing is that you should add declare your activity on your manifest file on the  tag like this :

```
<activity android:name="your.package.name.NameOfYourAcitivity" />
```

the last thing is : try to  instantiate the intent like this :

```
this.startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of...

```
case R.id.ibM4A1:
    Intent intentM4A1 = new Intent("com.maxgenero.droidarmory.M4A1GUN");
    startActivity(intentM4A1);
```

Try

```
Intent intentM4A1 = new Intent(this, ACTIVITY_NAME.class);
startActivity(intentM4A1);
```

Also dont forget to call your setOnclickListener().

Comment: This is a more simpler way to do it. Let me know if it helps out.

Comment: Putting "this" inside of a ClickListener will not provide any Context.  You should use the ActivityName.this